# What does "enable referees in your browser" mean

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I am trying to send an e-mails but it keeps coming back with "enable referees in my browser".I have put in Google Chrome but it is not accepted. Am not clear what they are asking for.

Comment: There are 0 google search results for "enable referees in my browser". Are you 100% certain this is what the error message says? What do you use for email?

Comment: Perhaps it's "referrer" you mean?

Comment: Hi Mavis, your question is very unclear.  Double-check the error message you are receiving, as "referees" would make no sense in this context.  What does this have to do with OneNote?  What do you mean it's "not accepted" when you try to "put it into Google Chrome"?

Answer (score 0):

It's a HTTP Header the browser sends, HTTP referer: *header field that identifies the address of the webpage* *The request includes the referrer field, which indicates the last page the user was on (the one where they clicked the link).*

http://www.technipages.com/firefox-enable-disable-referrer

```
Type about:config in the address bar and press Enter.
If prompted with a warning, select “I’ll be careful, I promise!“,
Find the entry that says Network.http.sendRefererHeader and double-click on it.
Set the entry to one of the following:

    0 – Disable referrer.
    1 – Send the Referer header when clicking on a link, and set document.referrer for the following page.
    2 – Send the Referer header when clicking on a link or loading an image
```